# Keep grub over windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, gparted

I resized a windows partition using gparted which moved the start of that partition and windows stopped working. I can repair it using windows disc but then it would put the windows boot loader on top.
Is there a way to repair windows while maintaining grub as the dominant boot loader.

Comment: what error does windows give you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can repair using the windows disk.

**FOR WINDOWS 7**

You probably just need to run (cmd):

```
Bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

and if it cannot locate any missing Windows installations run these three commands from windows cmd:

```
Bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
Bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Just don't run bootrec /fixmbr.

Then, boot up Ubuntu and run the followin command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

[boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) has once helped me when nothing else did. But don't forget to backup important data, just in case.

Comment: i know about boot repair i wanted to know it i can repair windows without disturbing grub